# How do I prevent npm install from removing packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to set up a development environment with several packages, and as a result I need to manually install some dependencies.  More specifically, I have some local changes in several packages which I need to test before I can push them to github, so I can't just `npm install` the top level because it won't pick up those change.  So I run the first `npm install` manually on packages which are missing, and then try to run my node code and see which package it is still missing, then try to `npm install` what it says is missing.

However, when I go to install the second package, it ends up with this message:

```
added 3 packages from 4 contributors, removed 799 packages and audited 3 packages in 4.197s
```

The second install removed practically *every* package that was already installed!  I didn't notice this until about the third time, when I realized that I seemed to be installing the same thing over and over.

However can I prevent this particularly naughty behavior and force npm to *only install what I tell it to and leave everything else alone*?

Comment: Turns out that not only did npm delete some installed packages, one of them was a local package that I had made changes on which were not saved because I was trying to get everything set up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at `npm link` if you need to test against modified packages.

From [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link):
*This is handy for installing your own stuff, so that you can work on it and test it iteratively without having to continually rebuild.*

Say `b` is a dependency of `a`. You made changes to `b` and want to check if `a` still works with those changes. Instead of using `b` in `node_modules` installed from `npm`, use your local, modified version:

```
cd ~/projects/b    # go into the package directory
npm link           # creates global link
cd ~/projects/a    # go into some other package directory.
npm link b         # link-install the package
```

Now, any changes to `~/projects/b` will be reflected in `~/projects/a/node_modules/b/`.

Comment: Well this works, but unfortunately now I have to re-install all dependencies of my package in development to its own directory, instead of being able to use the already installed dependencies in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

If your development flow involves **updating in parallel** packages which **depend on one another**, you might consider switching your project's package manager to from `npm` to `yarn` to take advantage of yarn's [**workspaces** feature](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/).

**Yarns's workspaces** allow you to easily setup a **single monorepo** containing all your interconnected dependencies, and let yarn thinking how to **link them together** in your dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem today , & thought this might help someone in the future and l have found out that if you install simultaneouly it

npm install --save package1 package2 package3 ...

it worked as l had

npm install xlsx  angular-oauth2-oidc

but if you install separately it will have issues

**Edit 2** More infor by **@Michael**

*installing multiple packages in the same command also prevents hooks from being installed multiple times*

Answer (score -3):

Are you saving the dependencies to package.json? 
To Save : `npm install --save {package_name}`. This will save the package to package.json and install using `npm install`.

You can't particularly control the dependencies(fully). The dependencies which you have installed might be using dependencies themselves.So when you remove a package, npm deletes all the package's dependencies and the package.