# Why does 'npm install' remove my installed packages in angular cli?

Tags: node.js, npm

The `npm install [package]` command is removing other packages previously installed.

If I run `npm install [package b]`, it will install package b but remove package a. This occurs vice versa with other packages.

This happens when install the *ng-bootstrap dependency* using the following command `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and later install the following dependency `npm install ng2-ion-range-slider --save`, in this case `ng-bootstrap dependency` is removed of my `node_modules`. My questions is why this happens? What is the explanation of this strange behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent npm install from removing packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452658/how-do-i-prevent-npm-install-from-removing-packages)

Comment: Can you post your package.json after you run "npm install --save [package]", to confirm the package is listed in the packge.json.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it happened due to outdated `package-lock.json` (it was not commited to git after latest `package.json` change).

**Solution**: do plain `npm i`  to fix your `package-lock.json`

After this `npm i [packages]` should work as expected

Comment: For me, ```npm list``` shows my packages as extraneous.  Running ```npm i``` deleted these.