# npm install removing dependencies. How to prevent?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have some dependencies installed which are not in my package json file. These are the packages that i have modified for the project.
While i install any new package by

```
npm install packageName
```

then my previous dependencies gets deleted.

```
digvijay@digvijay:~/playmoogley/development/triviaCode/triviador_gameserver$ npm install dotenv
npm WARN trivia-gameserver@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ dotenv@8.2.0
removed 322 packages, updated 1 package and audited 434 packages in 3.017s

25 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

How can I avoid this package removal and audited. I want only to install the dependency.

I need the step by step solution to do so without removing any dependencies i need to install new dependencies. If possible comment with appropriate commands to run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent npm install from removing packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452658/how-do-i-prevent-npm-install-from-removing-packages)

Comment: @federico-dondi No, i have tries to do so by npm link but it didn't worked. Can you suggest me some step by step solution?